# NFS over TCP not available from (My server ip) - network is unreachable & permission denied

Tags: virtualbox, nfs, dhcp, tftp

I am trying to boot linux mint from a server I set up in virtualbox. Server is running in linux mint, and the client that I'm testing on (also virtualbox) is disk-less and booting over network. After splash screen vmlinuz and initrd are received correctly, until I get the following error:

[image: error]

Any info on what might be going wrong?

Comment: 172.23.104.0 seems like an address for an entire network, not for a specific server. What config files have that address?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have two interfaces. eth0 on NAT and eth1 on internal network. eth1 is on address 172.23.104.0 with netmask 255.255.255.128. I am using dnsmasq and the config files that has that adress is the default config file that I have in /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249094/nfs-over-tcp-not-available-from-my-server-ip-network-is-unreachable-permis#comment428642_249094) pointed out, the most likely cause for this error is network misconfiguration: your `eth1` interface has been configured with the invalid address `172.23.104.0`.

Unfortunately, this was not my case. I was trying to make a Raspberry Pi 3 boot from NFS and my network, hosts and NFS shares were configured correctly. After having seen a whole range of obscure errors like:

> ```
> Begin: Retrying nfs mount ... short read: 24 < 28
> NFS over TCP not available from [Server IP address]
> pmap_getmaps.c: rpc problem: RPC: Authentication error; why = Client credential too weak
> mount: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
> ```

I finally found the answer [here](https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/sebuildla-a-ca-controlminder-creating-services-lookaside-database-pmapgetmapsc-rpc-problem-rpc-authentication-error-why-client-credential-too-weak/kb000004594) (but it was also at hand [here](http://www.anthonyldechiaro.com/blog/tag/pxeboot/)).

There was no mismatch between NFSv3 and NFSv4 in `nfsd.ko` module in the RPI3 kernel tree, nor it was a problem of architecture or whatever. It was simply a matter of allowing RPCs coming from my test subnetwork inside `/etc/hosts.allow`, like this:

> ```
> #> cat /etc/hosts.allow 
>
> rpcbind mountd nfsd statd lockd rquotad : 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 10.250.0.0/16
> ```

Comment: Correct answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SYSAPPEND 3` to your config file in pxelinux. This will append `ip=` and `BOOTIF=` parameters to the kernel.
See documentation here: https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#SYSAPPEND_bitmask

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1848018

I had the same problem with Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04.1 LTS

I know that the question is very old, but I don't mind :D

```
LABEL Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
  kernel /tftpboot/ubuntu/amd64/casper/vmlinuz
  append vga=normal netboot=nfs boot=casper ip=dhcp nfsroot=192.168.2.116:/tftpboot/ubuntu/amd64/ ro initrd=/tftpboot/ubuntu/amd64/casper/initrd locale=de_DE bootkbd=de console-setup/layoutcode=de
```

I forgot the "`ip=dhcp`" mentioned in the https://bugs.launchpad.net link above.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on Ubuntu 18.04 but with an updated 5.4 kernel to allow exporting overlayfs.

First to get rid of "Connection refused" I had to run:

```
    rpc.mountd
```

Then I got the above message. Simply restarting the NFS after that worked. Not sure what config files i need to update yet or if it's going to work after a reboot. Will report back.

```
/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart
```

I also had to run:

```
systemctl restart rpcbind
```

Comment: Worked fine after reboot too. So it's just necessary to make active any changes you made to `/etc/exports`.

Comment: ie. just `exportfs` clearly isn't enough anymore :-/